# scroll to the bottom of an extended div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I'm making a little test that is displaying footsteps and extending the div as the footsteps count grows.
I'm trying to get the user at the bottom of the pink div by using jquery, so he is always at the bottom as the div is growing.
I tried these kind of lines :

```
$(".two").scrollTop($(".two")[0].scrollHeight);
```

But nothing seems to work.

I wanted to ask for a fresh eye that could tell me what I'm doing wrong there!
Thanks a lot.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var nbFoot = 0 ;

  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) { 

    setTimeout(function () {

      nbFoot++;
      var footSteps = $("<div />", {"class": "footSteps"})
      .css({})
      .append($("<p>" + nbFoot + " pas </p>"))
      .appendTo(".one")
      $(".footSteps").prev().remove();
      $(".two").height( nbFoot +"00");
      $(".two").scrollTop($(".two")[0].scrollHeight);
    }, 200 * i)


      }

    });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #5a6c58;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100vh, auto);
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  position: fixed;
  height: 800px;
    background-color: tan;
}

.two,
.three,
.four {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffdbf5;
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.two {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

.three {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
}

.four {
  grid-column: 4 / 4;
}

.one::-webkit-scrollbar, 
.two::-webkit-scrollbar, 
.three::-webkit-scrollbar, 
.four::-webkit-scrollbar { 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>en ligne</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="one" id="gauche">    <div class="dir1"></div> </div>
        <div class="two" id="droite">    <div class="dir2"></div> </div>
    </div>
    <div class ="texte"></div>
<div class="note" style="display: none;">*</div>  

</body>

    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the window scroll top `$('window').scrollTop($(".two")[0].scrollHeight);` it will work for sure.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var nbFoot = 0 ;

  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) { 

    setTimeout(function () {

      nbFoot++;
      var footSteps = $("<div />", {"class": "footSteps"})
      .css({})
      .append($("<p>" + nbFoot + " pas </p>"))
      .appendTo(".one")
      $(".footSteps").prev().remove();
      $(".two").height(`${nbFoot}00`);
     $(window).scrollTop($(".two")[0].scrollHeight);
      
    }, 200 * i)


      }
      
    });
```

Comment: my bad...
Thanks a lot, these scrollTop things are tough to me...

Comment: @pual yes it can be confusing sometimes.. good luck with the rest of the code :)

Comment: might be on the website from time to time! haha